# change complex background with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background

i want to change the background-color of an
element with jquery from:

```
background: transparent linear-gradient(#C0B 45%, #C0B)
```

into:

```
background-color:#000;
```

i tried to remove the background-property with .removeAttr(),
but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below.

```
$('#element_id').css('background', 'none'); // remove background
$('#element_id').css('background-color', '#000'); // set background color
```

You can combine two line like below.

```
$('#element_id').css({'background':'none', 'background-color': '#000'});
```

Comment: no, i tried this before. it is not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/thebiz/4bb3d5wr/

Comment: I thought you have used  inline `css`. Anyway I've updated my answer. @thebiz

Answer (score 1):

i found a way. you have to do it like this:

```
$(this).css("background","none");
```

after that you can add your own background-properties.

Answer (score -1):

try
`$(this).css('background-color', 'red');`